¿Como obtengo el estado de pago en mercado pago checkout pro version 2.6.1?
tengo el checkout integrado y con las tarjetas de prueba puedo simular todo el proceso de pago hasta que este sea correcto o incorrecto pero estoy teniendo problemas al capturar el pago para posteriormente actualizar ciertos valores de la pagina web y en la base de datos, osea necesito tener el id del pago.
Esta es la integracion:
    $accestoken="tutoken";
MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken($accestoken);
$preference=new MercadoPago\Preference();
$compra=0;


$productos=array();
$productosmp=unserialize($_COOKIE['products']??'');

  $compra=rand(1,100000);
  if(is_array($productosmp)==false){
    $productosmp=array();
    foreach ($productosmp as $producto){
      $item=new MercadoPago\Item();
       $item->title=$producto['prod_nombre'];
       $item->quantity=$producto['prod_cant'];
       $item->currency_id="ARS";
       $item->unit_price=$producto['prod_precio'];
       $item->id=$producto["id_prod"];
       array_push($productos,$item);
    }



 $preference->binary_mode=true;
 $preference->back_urls=array(
  "success"=>"http://localhost/pps1pruebanode/pagosuccess.php",
  "failure"=>"http://localhost/pps1pruebanode/pagofail.php"
 );
 $preference->auto_return="approved"; 
 $preference->external_reference=$compra;
 $preference->items=$productos;




  

   $preference->save();

He intentado accediendo a estos endpoint pero nada osea no me marca un error pero tampoco me muestra el id en la pagina.
$objMercadoPago = new  MercadoPago\Payment();

   $paymp=$objMercadoPago->get("https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/{$compra}");
  $pay2mp=$preference->get("https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/{$preference->id}");
echo $compra;


echo $datos2json = $objMercadoPago -> get("/v1/payments/search?external_reference={$compra}");


Usando el API de desarrollo...

la sdk cambio  ahora hay una sdk3 con nuevas clases y los ejemplos son con la nueva sdk que tiene nuevas clases y no encontre documentacion sobre la sdk 2 para hacer lo que quiero

y no deberias de migrar a esa version??? es mas segura etc, etc, etc ...

tienes otras opciones como contratar a un especialista en el tema: https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es

o preguntar en el discord: https://discord.com/invite/yth5bMKhdn
